# How to smoothen a function at the origin?

Tags: real-analysis

Is it possible to construct a multivariate nonnegative function $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R_+$ in such a way that $f(x)$ is smooth (e.g. twice continuously differentiable) everywhere and $f(x)=\|x\|^p$ when $\|x\|$ is large enough, where $p\in(0,1)$? Note that $\|x\|^p$ is not twice continuously differentiable at the origin.

It appears intuitively clear but how do I construct the function explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following proposal does not provide equality with $\|x\|^p$ for large $\|x\|$, but it consists of a simple expression. Depending on the application you have in mind this might be sufficient for your purposes.

Choose a small $\epsilon>0$ and consider the function
$$f(x):=\bigl(\epsilon^2+\|x\|^2\bigr)^{p/2}\ .$$

Comment: I inferred the question as wanting actual equality, not just an approximation, for large $x$.

Comment: As @Hurkyl points out, I'd like an equality. Thanks though!

Comment: @WilliamZhang This is easily fixed by replacing $\epsilon$ with some smooth bump function $\epsilon(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

You can reduce it to the following problem: find a sufficiently smooth functions $g$ and $h$ such that $g(x) = 0$ and $h(x) > 0$ on a neighborhood of the origin and both $g(x) = 1$ and $h(x) = 0$ outside of a larger neighborhood of the origin.

Then you can just use $f(x) = \|x\|^p g(x) + h(x)$.

You could just let $h(x) = 1 - g(x)$, so that they form a [partition of unity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_unity). Then it's common to express this problem in terms of $h$, which is a [bump function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function).

Comment: Thanks a lot! (At first, I was thinking of $\|x\|^p e^{-\|x\|^{-2}}$.) I still have a little confusion. If $h(x)$ is the bump function example on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function), then how can $g(x)=1-h(x)$ be zero on the neighbourhood of the origin?

Comment: @WilliamZhang With this particular example, $g$ isn't equal to $0$ on some neighborhood, but there are other functions that do the trick. Yet, the proposed $f$ still does the trick, because, while $g$ isn't zero on some neighborhood of $0$, it still has all its derivatives equal to zero at $0$.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat In a neighbourhood, the derivative of $\|x\|^p g(x)$ is $\frac{p}{\|x\|^{1-p}}g(x) + \|x\|^p g'(x)$. The first term would have trouble unless $g(x)=1-h(x)$ goes to 0 fast enough as $\|x\|\to 0$, which is not the case for the current bump function $h(x)$.